# Min within a Lambda on a single Line

Tags: c#, lambda, min

Just looking for the nicest way to handle the following line and to keep it to one line...

```
if (int.TryParse(data.Min(x => x.ItemArray[i].ToString()), out result))
```

contained in the following routine...

```
var data = model.Data.AsEnumerable();

  for (int i = 0; i < model.Data.Columns.Count; i++)
  {
    int result;
    if (int.TryParse(data.Min(x => x.ItemArray[i].ToString()), out result))
    {
      model.Minimum.Add(DataTableUtility.MinValue(result));
    }
  }
```

This works fine until the ItemArray contains rows with no values (empty objects).  Is there is simple way to keep this to a single line and handle this situation?

Comment: Can you explain what this line is expected to do? `int.Parse(y.ToString())` always look suspicious - there possible better way of checking for "no values"... Especially for data type that already support ordering for Min to work...

Comment: Its simply a part of a larger function that iterates through a table producing maximum and minimum values for charts.  The conversion to string simply converts it to a value that can be parsed (or at least attempted) and create the metrics if the column is indeed  numeric of some sort.   Just want a simple way to keep it a one-liner.  Looked at .DefaultIfEmpty also.  There must be a really simple way to do this?

Comment: What type is ItemArray?

Comment: What do you want to add when a row is empty? `MaxValue`? Zero? Nothing (it will be hard to tell from your `Minimum` column which number belongs to which row if you do not add something).

Answer (score 0):

There are methods defined in the `DataRow` and `DataColumn` classes that you really should be using.  Assuming each column in your table is a nullable int, you could do this:

```
var mins =
    from row in table.AsEnumerable()
    select (from DataColumn c in table.Columns
            where !row.IsNull(c)
            select row.Field<int>(c)).Min();
```

If you have mixed types, check the type and only accept ints:

```
var mins =
    from row in table.AsEnumerable()
    select (from DataColumn c in table.Columns
            where !row.IsNull(c)
            where c.DataType == typeof(int)
            select row.Field<int>(c)).Min();
```

If you're actually storing integers as strings... then you have other problems... Then you have to parse it out.  Just don't try to be clever.  Create a method to try and parse out the values and return a value on success, 0 (or null) otherwise.

```
int? TryConvertInt32(obj value)
{
    try { return Convert.ToInt32(value); } catch { return default(int?); }
}

var mins =
    from row in table.AsEnumerable()
    select row.ItemArray.Select(v => TryConvertInt32(v) ?? 0).Min();
```

et cetera...

Answer (score 0):

I realised the conversion to string was a bracket early causing it to min by the string value.  After this of course the casting of more complex types such as double needed further handling.   Couldn't get it completely on one line, but the working solution (as a hybrid to some of these suggestions is as follows...

var data = model.Data.AsEnumerable();

```
  for (int i = 0; i < model.Data.Columns.Count; i++)
  {
    int result;
    if (int.TryParse(data.Min(x => TryConvertInt32((x.ItemArray[i] is System.DBNull || x.ItemArray[i] == null ? int.MaxValue : x.ItemArray[i]))).ToString(), out result))
    {
      model.Minimum.Add(DataTableUtility.MinValue(result));
    }
  }
```

with static "handler" as suggested above..

private static int? TryConvertInt32(object o)
    {
      try
      {
        return Convert.ToInt32(o);
      }
      catch
      {
        return default(int?);
      }
    }

Answer (score -1):

Easy:

```
 if (int.TryParse(data.Min(x => (x.ItemArray[i] ?? int.MaxValue).ToString()), out result))
```

Just add the biggest value possible for int, as you are looking for min values those will be discarded.

EDIT:

So, if I understand then you will have ANY type checked there, so this is better:

```
if (int.TryParse(data.Min(x => (x.ItemArray[i] ?? "").ToString()), out result))
```

In this way on null items TryParse will fail.

EDIT:

Support for dbnull:

```
if (int.TryParse(data.Min(x => (x.ItemArray[i] is System.DBNull || x.ItemArray[i] == null ? "" : x.ItemArray[i]).ToString()), out result))
```

Comment: Given that the OP is using `.ToString` followed by `int.Parse` I would imagine that the OP does not have `ItemArray : IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: I had tried something similar.  Noticed objects in the array are coming in as -{} object {System.DBNull}

Comment: Yep variant of the above is definitely the way to go... if (int.TryParse(data.Min(x => (x.ItemArray[i] is System.DBNull || x.ItemArray[i] == null ? int.MaxValue : x.ItemArray[i]).ToString()), out result))

Comment: Beware, using int.MaxValue if all the fields are DBNull will yield 2146697215 instead of zero, because of that I changed it to "", to make the parse fail and skip it.

Comment: Also, a little question, your data is stored as integers (the one you care about)? If yes, then why don't skyp non-integer values? Something like var ints = data.Select(i => i is int).ToArray(); if(ints.Length > 0) model.Minimum.Add(ints.Min());

Answer (score -1):

You don't want to do this...

The simple reason, WHY you shouldn't do this?

Because this does not convey intent. What on earth is `ItemArray`, why are you `.ToString`ing it? Are you sure you don't want to do a safe cast? What about culture? How should you parse the string "1,234" (on the continent, that is "one point two three four", whilst an english speaker would parse that as "one thousand two hundred and thirty four")?

Are you sure you don't want

```
var results = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, model.Data.Columns.Count)
              where data.Min(x => x.ItemArray.OfType<int>().DefaultIfEmpty())
              select temp;
```

Comment: ItemArray is an object array because it represents a row on a table, so,  he can't cast it to int.

Comment: @Gusman...wow...you really don't understand what `.OfType<int>()` does then. That is precisely why you want to use `IEnumerable.OfType<int>()`.